# multiline lightning:helptext

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:helptext
        content="Your email address will be your login name" />
</aura:component>
```

we can include dynamic text by using a variable

```
<aura:component>
        <lightning:helptext
            content="{!v.helpText}" />
    </aura:component>
```

I want to make the text multiline or introduce bullet or want to insert HTML code there is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. Only plain text is allowed, so there's no way to get line breaks or other formatting in to the text. This is a limitation of how the component is designed. If you really want to do this, you can implement inline help from the SLDS:

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
<label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-unique-id">Form Element Label</label>
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
<input type="text" id="input-unique-id" class="slds-input" placeholder="Placeholder Text" />
</div>
<div class="slds-form-element__help">ex: (415)111-2222</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per stack-exchange, it is one of the most viewed question. I have found one free app exchange product that helped me to cater to the requirements for me. I hope It will help others as well

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000G0nQuUAJ

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce doesn't provide custom styling as of now. Best option seems to use slds design.

[Refer to this complete example here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/348444/99388)