# How to show line by line content using Lightning Tooltip or helptext

Tags: lightning, helptext

Currently, my lightning helptext tag is as below:

```
<lightning:helptext iconName="utility:info" content="Small = < 3MM, 

                                                     Medium = 3MM - 25MM 

                                                     Large = >25MM" />
```

And the result is [image]

But I want to show it line by line on the toolip(helptext)

Ex:

```
Small=<3M
Medium =3M-20M
Large = >25M
```

Please share the solution

Comment: Are you saying you want to show the values in new line for all values (as edited in the post now)? Or its something different?

Answer (score 5):

You can't do any additional formatting inside `lightning:helptext`, including forcing line breaks. The content attribute is treated as a plain text string, so any attempts to provide any additional formatting will fail to work. Instead, you would need to use normal SLDS [tooltips](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tooltips/). This means you'd have to write all that logic yourself, including showing/hiding the text, etc.

Answer (score 5):

###### salesforce still doesn't support styling for help text, for workaround slds tooltips works. Here's an example

[image]

HTML

```
<div style="position:relative">
   <div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1">Input Label</label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__icon">
        <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon" onmouseover={togglePasswordHint}
            onmouseout={togglePasswordHint}>
            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:info" alternative-text="Info" size="xx-small"
                title="">
            </lightning-icon>
        </button>
        <div class={passwordHintClass} role="tooltip" id="help"
            style="position:absolute;top:-100px;left:-15px;width:200px">
            <div class="slds-popover__body">
                Password must contain: <br>
                At least 8 characters, <br>
                At least 1 uppercase letter, <br>
                At least 1 lowercase letter, <br>
                At least 1 number, <br>
                At least 1 special character.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1" placeholder="Placeholder text…"
            class="slds-input" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In js file

```
passwordHintClass = "slds-popover slds-popover_tooltip slds-nubbin_bottom-left slds-fall-into-ground slds-hide"
togglePasswordHint() {
    this.passwordHintClass = this.passwordHintClass == 'slds-popover slds-popover_tooltip slds-nubbin_bottom-left slds-fall-into-ground slds-hide' ? "slds-popover slds-popover_tooltip slds-nubbin_bottom-left slds-rise-from-ground" : "slds-popover slds-popover_tooltip slds-nubbin_bottom-left slds-fall-into-ground slds-hide"
}
```

---

NOTE

> style="position:absolute;top:-100px;left:-15px;width:200px">

we may have to adjust top position and sometimes width to fit the tooltip properly.
In the example I'm using some long help text so -100px. for small texts -60 to -65px is enough.

otherwise it keeps toggling randomly.